# C# WCF Easier way to update host DLLs

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

Maybe I am just doing this poorly from the start but right now whenever I update my WCF service, I use the following process.

1. Save The service Class Library
2. Clean and Then Build the solution
3. Right Click the services host application project and select Edit WCF Configuration
4. Navigate to the Services Class and "reload" it
5. Save the configuration
6. clean and then build the solution again
7. run the solution

I have a feeling there has got to be a better way, like with connected services I can just right click the service and click update.

Comment: Why are you performing a _"clean"_ step each time?

Comment: _[WCF the Manual Way… the Right Way](http://www.codemag.com/article/0809101)_